# Meta data image for Facebook

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-universal

I want to use images if I shere some links of my site. Well I am using following for it:

```
        import { Meta, Title } from "@angular/platform-browser";
        this.title.setTitle(this.data[0].title + ' - ' + this.data[0].city 
        );

        this.meta.addTags([

          { name: 'keywords', content: 'Globetrotter, Backpacking, Hiking, Travel' + this.data[0].city + ',' + this.data[0].country},
          { name: 'description', content: this.data[0].description},
          { name: 'og:image', content: this.data[0].images[0]}
        ]);
```

Everything works fine but with image not and I am not sure if is correct. Within my index.html file I have an another image and this is occuring. Should I delete it? How can I set also the url for displaying the entire site automatically?

**index.html**
Facebook always shows this images even if I enter different url path.

```
<meta property="og:image"     content="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/01/21/53/blue-2705642_960_720.jpg"
 />
```

I want that Facebook or other sites recognise the image from here:

```
 { name: 'og:image', content: this.data[0].images[0]}
```

Comment: Can you detail what exactly works and what does not? Does Facebook "see" the other meta tags?

Comment: see above. I have an index.html file with meta property="og:image" . FB always use this. I need to overwrite with the new image of the new site.

Comment: @RyanGadsdon, you need to be more careful where you add line breaks in your edits. You have introduced syntax errors by breaking in the middle of string literals [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17698833), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17700358), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17694798) and also your [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17700359) on this question. Even ones that don't add errors often [harm readability](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17698017) rather than improve it.

Comment: @Bryan all i did was format your code. I didnt change anything

Comment: Ok any suggestion for my problem ? :-)

Comment: It's not my code @RyanGadsdon. And, yes, you did change it. After your edit, there was an error in the code that was not there before. And you're [still](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17708836) [doing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17709243) [it](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17706172).

Comment: @Bryan i dont understand how formatting the code to one page would give you an error. i didnt change the actual code in anyway

Comment: @RyanGadsdon, [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17706172) resulted in code that [does not even compile](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PLW5Y8). The others I linked above produce similar errors.

Comment: @Bryan Strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably, that facebook's crawler/bot does not execute JavaScript and thus will only ever see the `<meta>` tag you deliver statically in your `index.html`.

You will either have to use a prerendering service (like prerender.io) or write the correct meta tag on the server side.